# DynamicReports + Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, dynamic-reports

I wonder how to use Hibernate dataset as datasource for DynamicReports. I don't have a clue about it and can't google any acceptable solution.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend you to send an email to Ricardo Mariaca, he is the developer of the library and he is always helping to the community

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to solve similar task - using ejbql with DynamicReports. I've made it work using a little bit of native JasperReports API. Here is my walkaround.

```
JasperReportBuilder builder = report()
.columns(
        col.column("CriterionName",       "CriterionName",      type.stringType()),
        col.column("Description",   "Description",  type.stringType()) )
      .title(Templates.createTitleComponent("entityManagerDatasource"))
      .pageFooter(Templates.footerComponent)
      .setQuery("SELECT c.CriterionName, c.Description from ConfigCriterions c", 
    QueryLanguage.EJBQL)
      .addParameter(JRJpaQueryExecuterFactory.PARAMETER_JPA_ENTITY_MANAGER, entityManager);
    JasperDesign design = builder.toJasperDesign();
    List<JRField> fields = design.getFieldsList();
    int i = 0;
    for (JRField field:fields)  {
        ++i;
        field.setDescription("COLUMN_" + i);
    }       

    JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(design);
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, null);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I solved my problem by using DynamicJasper instead of DynamicReports.